# Get the view of an Admob InterstitialAd

Tags: android, admob, android-view, ontouchlistener

I have Interstitial ads in my app but I would like to implement an OnTouchListener to the view of the InterstitialAd when it appears but there is no direct way of doing so in the InterstitialAd class like there is in AdView for banner ads. So my question is how can I get the view of the Interstitial ad when it appears so I can set an OnTouchListener to it ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well surely the InterstitialAd class ads a View to the screen when you call InterstitialAd.show() I want to find a way to get that view when I display it , I would like to add a touch listener to the view so I can run some code when a user clicks an ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdMob does not provide a means to directly access the view hierarchy for an interstitial ad. This is done intentionally for a number of reasons relating to both policy and design.

As AndroidMechanic pointed out, however, you can use an AdListener to receive events that tell you what's going on with an ad. If you'd like to know when an ad was clicked, for example, you can use [onAdLeftApplication](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdLeftApplication()), which is called when a user has tapped on an ad, causing a browser or other app to open in response.

Answer (score 2):

Admob aleady provides the `AdListener` interface for this.

You can implement the `AdListener` interface  and then use the `public void onAdClosed ()` method to do whatever you want when the user returns to your app after viewing the ad or clicking on it. Read more in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener#public-method-summary)

As per the documentation in this link the method is called as follows:

> Called when the user is about to return to the application after
>   clicking on an ad.

Comment: I am well aware of the AdListener but this is not what I need , I need to get the view added to the screen when the show() method is called for an interstitial ad

Comment: you mean you want to show the interstitial ad inside your activity? I'm afraid that is not possible and not allowed as well.

Comment: Well the Interstitial ad is launched from inside your activity as far as I know I am not sur if it is an Intent or something else I have not done some research on that but I am guessing you have some control over it since all the ad click etc can be detected with an adlistener etc